# How to give access to Google Play Developer Console Game services page to other accounts?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

We have a game on Google play created with a developer account and then we have admin access to that game trough our personal accounts (we are multiple developers). Recently, I have added achievements to that game using the Game Services page, the problem now is that we can only access to that game through my personal account or the developer account (the account owner) but not the other personal accounts.

Anyone knows if it is possible to give permissions to other users to access the Game Services page for a specific game to see/modify achievements and other stuff?

Comment: Nope, we still have to use the admin account to be sure we have access to everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after talking with Google support, it seems there is a page to control which accounts has access to which games, it is https://console.developers.google.com, and from there you can configure permissions without problems and it works (tested it). You have to sign in as the account owner to have full access to all games.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to **Settings** > **User Accounts & Rights**, you can click on the **Invite New User** button to add additional users to this account. Then, those other users should be able to edit achievements and leaderboards and the like.

Please note, however, that this will allow them to view / edit *all* applications created with your account, not just specific ones.

Comment: That doesn't work, we added a new user recently and he can't see what other users have created under the google game services page. I believe this only works if the google game services stuff is created with the dev account owner.