# Can NOT re-publish my Game

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

So yesterday I Unpublished my Game from Game Services tab because was crashing.
Today I solve some issues and I'm trying to publish it again.

When I select the option "Re-Publish Game" on top-left selector I get:

"You currently don't have the necessary rights to republish this game. Please ask the owner of the 'Unknown Project' project to grant you access."

[Game Services: Ready to republish but without permission(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFgVS.png)

The project now called "Unknown Project" contains a link to IAM-ADMIN, where I can see this:

[IAM: You don't have permissions to perform the action on the selected resource.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmTZs.png)

NOTES:
 1. I'm able to create a "New Release" from "All applications->Release management" without any issue.. BUT, I can NOT edit the same Application in "Game Services". In other words, the game still published but not editable from Game Services.

Please, some help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may check in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en) that the app may be rejected due to a violation of Google Play policies. More information about the violation is available near the top of your app's pages on the Play Console. Once you make a change to your app to address the violation, you can submit it again. You may also refer with this SO thread: [How to give access to Google Play Developer Console Game services page to other accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896448/how-to-give-access-to-google-play-developer-console-game-services-page-to-other). It stated that from this [link](https://console.developers.google.com), you can configure permissions without problems. You have to sign in as the account owner to have full access to all games.