# Google play api access oauth

Tags: google-api, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, google-play-console

I'm making an application to read and respond to the reviews of google play account for my applications. When I enter my google play account, settings > api access, the following message appears to me: "Only the account owner can configure API access. Please contact him to update the API settings."
Is it possible that the owner of the account that has published the application gives me permissions to generate the token only to read the reviews? Or only the owner can generate a global token to read the reviews?.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, API can only be configured by the owner of [Google Play Developer account](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#account-details). As an account owner, you can add users to your Play Console account and manage permissions across all apps or for specific apps. From this [page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en):

> 1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
> 2. Click Settings **Settings** > **User accounts & rights**.
>
>    - To add a new user, select **Invite new user** and follow the on-screen instructions.
>    - To update permissions for an existing user, hover over their email address and select the pencil icon Pencil icon.
> 3. Use the "Role" drop-down to choose a pre-defined role or use the checkboxes for individual permissions.
> 4. Choose whether each permission applies to all apps in your developer account ("Global") or specific apps.
>
>    - To add an app to the permissions table, use the "Add an app" drop-down Drop-down arrow.
>    - To see details for each permission, review the [permission definitions
>        table](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691#definitions).
> 5. Click **Send Invitation**.

You can only generate a token once you're added as an [owner](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691).

Additional reference:

- [How to give access to Google Play Developer Console Game services page to other accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896448/how-to-give-access-to-google-play-developer-console-game-services-page-to-other)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I have already done what you have told me, and if I have been able to respond reviews, I have granted permissions and if I could. But will you know if there is any permission to read the reviews? I have not seen it read reviews in google api for android api. Regards